# Comparing a hit with next/previous hit

Tags: algolia, react-instantsearch

I’m looking to implement a separator between hits that’s conditional based on a comparison with the next/previous hit.

An example of what I’m trying to accomplish can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaBEy.png)

I’m developing in React Native where I’m using connectInfiniteHits from react-instantsearch-native, but I’ve hit a wall in regards to accessing the next hit from a given hit.

Any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Comment: With the `FlatList` component in `renderItem` you have access to the current hit `item` and the `index`. With `data[index+1/index-1]` you should be able to achieve what you want. https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem